# E0145 member "boost::filesystem::path::separator" may not be initialized & LINK2019 error in VS2017 using vcpkg

Tags: c++, boost, vcpkg

I start using vcpkg in my msvc C++ project recently.

I built the boost 1.67 and referred it in my vs project. After I installed vcpkg, I added some lib and vcpkg seems installed another boost for me and link it to my project. Unfortunately, that boost does't work. I am now having tens of error in building project. Most of them are E0145 and LINK2019. I'm new in c++ programming. I want to know how I can use the boost I built instead of the one vcpkg installed for me.

eg. one of the error is because it changes my BOOST_NO_CXX11_CONSTEXPR and try to use constexpr while it's not supported on my pc. The error is:

```
E0145 member "boost::filesystem::path::separator" may not be initialized    c:\Users\admin\Libraries\boost_1_67_0\boost_1_67_0\boost\filesystem\path.hpp    65
```

this is my own boost file but all refer is to c:\Users\xxx\vcpkg\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows\include\boost\config\detail\suffix.hpp

instead of

C:\Users\xxx\Libraries\boost_1_67_0\boost_1_67_0\include\boost-1_67\boost\config\detail\suffix.hpp

What can I do to correct this? 
The file structure of vcpkg-boost is differ from the boost 1.67 I used before. If I replace the files with 1.67 ones, I'm afraid it will be reset when I upgrade the vcpkg and its libraries. Please give me some advice on this.

And I also got error like,

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl boost::filesystem::path_traits::convert(char const *,char const *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > &,class std::codecvt<wchar_t,char,struct _Mbstatet> const &)"......
```

Comment: Visual Studio has nothing to do with boost. You are in control of `additional include folders` and `additional libs` I've been working with the latest boost with 2017 and 2017 Preview, and my workhorse 2015. Get the updates and have had no issues. Try a simple console app with a minimum of code to see if it is really some kind of VS problem.

Comment: @lakeweb Thank you for the response. I have deleted all the links to boost and try to rebuild and reinstall boost via vcpkg. It seems fine for now. I still wonder how vcpkg link its libs to vs. I am new in msvc but I will keep learning.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I miss understood what vcpkg was. I did some reading. Personally, I would not use it to install boost. Boost 'installs' very simply on its own. I think one would be better off understanding includes and linking rather than depending on an installer.

Comment: I haven't resolved it. This error comes back while I didn't change any project properties